# Memory Leak and WebGLContextLost

Tags: reactjs, three.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, webgl

I have a TypeScript React component that loads multiple 3D models using Three.js and displays them in specific positions based on the values of an array from the backend (data[frame]). I create a renderer and a camera using useRef, and I also have OrbitControls. I can switch frames as much as I want and view the desired frames. However, when viewing approximately 80-100 frames, the browser suddenly turns black for a few seconds, and then the blackness disappears, then the following message is logged in the console:

> WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost

I clear the scene and renderer, but it doesn't really help with this error.

```
return () => {
    renderer.current?.dispose();
    renderer.current?.clear();
    scene.clear();
};
```

I tried to stop using useRef on the camera and disable OrbitControls. I also tried not to change the position of the models but instead load new models in their place. However, things only got worse because of the latter approach, so I gave up on that idea.
I found out that for first 20 frames memory using is like 1-10mb per frame, but later it became 30-50mb. I turned off cache saving but it didn't help at all, something is saving somewhere, but what and where I don't know

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by clearing groups that contains models, not only scene

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).